# cakephp search in several models and pagination

Tags: cakephp, search

Know how to do a search on several models in CakePHP?, and be able to page?

I found several plugins and others, but none refers to several models.

https://github.com/dogmatic69/cakephp_search_plugin

https://github.com/tkyk/cakephp-search-pagination

https://github.com/OldWest/cakephp-search-plugin-v1.1

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact that CakeDCs search plugin does work across models.

you can use an enhanced version here:
https://github.com/dereuromark/search